# Looking for a complete TUI script for configuring date and networking of CentOS 5

Tags: configuration

I'm looking for a script that allows complete configuration of a CentOS 5 system via TUI (no GUI, X, etc.).

I found system-config-network-tui but other than the fact it looks unprofessional (typos, bugs, etc.) I actually would like to find a script which supports the configuration of many other aspects (such as date/time, timezone, routing, etc.)

Is there anything available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try [setuptool](http://linux.maruhn.com/sec/setuptool.html) ?

Install it with `yum install setuptool`